# how to use raw sql with laravel eloquent builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get name and id from my user table, name is in two column as `first_name` and `last_name`. This is what I have done

```
$user = User::select('id',DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ' ,`last_name`) AS name"))
        ->where('name', 'like' ,$token)
```

which gives me an error **`Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'`**. I printed out the raw sql which looks like this

```
select `id`, CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ' ,`last_name`) AS name from `user` where `name` like ? and `user`.`deleted_at` is null
```

How can I use concat and like with my eloquent builder properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$user = User::select('id',DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ' ,`last_name`) AS name"))
        ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)"), 'LIKE', "%".$token."%");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use like that

```
$user = User::select('id',DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ' ,last_name) as name"))
        ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ' ,last_name)"), 'like' ,"%".$token."%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$user = User::select('Tenant_Id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name'))
        ->where('name', 'like' ,$token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$user = User::select('id',DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ' ,`last_name`) AS name"))
    ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`,' ', `last_name`)"), 'LIKE', "%" . $name . "%");
```

It worked for me.